# Illegal character in path at index for ^ and " " in angular Js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, encoding, encodeuricomponent

I am new to Angular Js  . I am encoding a string which is a part of `url` . 
My code is like this -

```
if(item.match(pattern))
                        {
                            url = 'rez/gazetteer/' + resourceName + '/' + docType + '/' + encodeURIComponent(item);
                        } 
                            console.log(" contains special character" +item);
                            url = 'rez/gazetteer/' + resourceName + '/' + docType + '/' + item;
                    }
```

It is calling my delete API . So , String  contains special characters , because of that I , have encoded It . But this is working for all special characters , except `" " and  ^`. These two also works on my local machine , but on remote instance it is giving error . can any one help me to solve this issue ?

Comment: Please provide more information about urls after encoding, also take a look at encodings. http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp

Comment: So , currently ,When there is word which contains  ^ . Then that url is not getting called .But encoding is there .